# NOT NULL constraint failed: IntegrityError

Tags: django-models, django-views

Trying a django project from the documentations.
**This is my Models.py** I am trying to make a simple employee goals management system. I have also used DRF and serializers, integrated swagger for only doing 'GET' of the models below. I have removed (commented out) all ForeignKey and ManyToMany Fields yet, when I add modify the goal or project I get this error. I cant seem to solve this, please help.

```
 class Department(models.Model):
    department_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    department_location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    department_region = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    department_site = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    department_job_titles = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.department_name


class Employee(models.Model):
    #department_name = models.ManyToManyField(Department)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #employee_id = models.IntegerField()
    supervisor_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    doj = models.DateTimeField('date joined')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

class Objectives(models.Model):
    objective_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #employee = models.ManyToManyField(Employee)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.objective_name


class Project(models.Model):
    #employee = models.ManyToManyField(Employee)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name

class Goals(models.Model):
    goal_id = models.IntegerField()
    goal_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #department = models.ManyToManyField(Department)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #objective_id = models.ManyToManyField(Objectives)
    goal_start = models.DateTimeField('date goal added')
    goal_end = models.DateTimeField('date goal ends')
    #employee = models.ManyToManyField(Employee)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.goal_name
```

**This is my views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .models import Employee
from .models import Goals
from .models import Objectives
from .models import Department
from .models import Project
from .serializers import EmployeeSerializer
from .serializers import ProjectSerializer
from .serializers import GoalsSerializer
from .serializers import ObjectivesSerializer
from .serializers import DepartmentSerializer
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view


schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='UpYourGame API')

#just a view if someone hits the index
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello and Welcome to UpyourGame")


# this will be the URL /employee/
class Employee(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        employee = Employee.objects.all()
        serializer = EmployeeSerializer(employee, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class Project(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        project = Project.objects.all()
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(project, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


class Goals(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        goals = Goals.objects.all()
        serializer = GoalsSerializer(goals, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class Objectives(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        objectives = Objectives.objects.all()
        serializer = ObjectivesSerializer(objectives, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

#class Company(APIView):
 #   def get(self, request):
  #      company = Company.objects.all()
   #     serializer = CompanySerializer(company, many=False)
    #    return Response(serializer.data)

class Department(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        department = Department.objects.all()
        serializer = DepartmentSerializer(Department, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**This is myproject/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from enterprise import views


urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.schema_view, name='schema_view'),
    url(r'^enterprise/', include('enterprise.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^employee/', views.Employee.as_view()),
    url(r'^goals/', views.Goals.as_view()),
    url(r'^department/', views.Department.as_view()),
    url(r'^department/', views.Department.as_view()),
    url(r'^objectives/', views.Objectives.as_view()),
    url(r'^project/', views.Project.as_view()),

]
```

**This is my serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Employee
from .models import Goals
from .models import Objectives
from .models import Department
from .models import Project


class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'


#class EmployeeDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

 #   class Meta:
  #      model = EmployeeDetails
   #     fields = '__all__'

class ObjectivesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Objectives
        fields = '__all__'


class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = '__all__'

#class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

#    class Meta:
#        model = Company
#        fields = '__all__'

class GoalsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Goals
        fields = '__all__'

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQLlite DB was corrupt due to too many migrations, it can happen. I deleted SQLlite and all my migrations, I retried migrate, makemigrate and sqlmigrate, it resolved the issue. 
If you run into a similar issue in a dev environment please try the following
1. Delete all your migrations in the `migrations` folder
2. Delete db.sqlite3 
3. Run `python manage.py migrate`
4. Run `python manage.py makemigrations`
5. Run `python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001`

This will fix this issue.